# UIWebView not showing when select row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have try all the method recommend in `SOF` but still cannot solve my problem.

this is in my `UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
  if ([[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a9"]||[[[AryStoreknowItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a9"]){

       NSString *a9 = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];

       NSLog(@" url from XML; %@  ",a9);

       webView *web=[[webView alloc]init];
       [web viewDidLoad];//go to webView page
```

when i select this row, it will detect the URL from XML and open the `UIWebView` but its not working. in `NSLog` show it detect these url;http://www.google.com

webView page;

```
#import "webView.h"
#import "inboxData.h"

@interface webView ()

@end

@implementation webView

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *a9 = [defaults objectForKey:@"a9"];

    NSLog(@"URL from inboxData get from XML detect >>> %@",a9);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:a9];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

can anyone give any idea how to solve this?

Comment: where you added the webview???in cell???in same screen where the uitableview is added?

Comment: @Bhavik Kama i've modified my code and add the webView page but still cannot open the webView..see edit question above..anyway, thanx for your help

Comment: you don't call manually [web viewDidLoad] like that.

Comment: oh man... you cant mannually call viewDidload... and where have you added the webview?? see my answer

Comment: @karthika..i also have try presentModalViewCOntroller but got crash on that line..how to call the webview page in right way?

Comment: if you used navigationController, use pushViewController, or add as a subview.[self.view addsubview:web];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems incomplete// first you don't show that where you adding the uiwebview ... or if your `UIWebView` is in the another screen then you didn't show that you have navigate to that screen or not.

So from the code you have given i can tell you that u dint add your UIWebView to the Some View so it cant be shown.... for sure..

so just try adding the UIWebview with some frame in the following way

i have just tried your code with the simple string as u said you have sure that your string is coming in proper way..and its working for me...

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    // above i had set the frame for UIWebView

    [web loadRequest:requestObj];
    web.delegate = self;
    [ParentView addSubview:web];//here i am adding the UIWebiView
```

Here `Parentview` will be the view where you want to add the UIWebView

Comment: ..i have try it but still nothing happen when i click that row..can u tell me in detail about that ParentView? sorry for asking stupid question..i newbie in xcode

Comment: ok..just write [self.view addSubview:web]; and u will see that above your uitableview that will be uiwebview loaded with google.com//just try this and let me knw

Comment: thanx bro..it work..but i need to modified the ui..bcoz the webview appear at the first row of my tableView..anyway,thank you so much! can i simple add the frame so that the webview?it is because the  header of tableview still appear above that webview

Comment: just change the x,y cordinates of your uiwebview frame as where you want to add the view.. u need to also set the uitabelview frame with respect to uiwebview position after view didselectrow method called

Comment: another request, how can i add back button in webview and go back to tableview(inboxData)? i already add the closed button but it will go to the main page instead of tableview(inboxData)

Comment: you need to navigate the view to the uiwebview.. please refer how to navigate the view on uitableview didselect method in google.. u will find lots of link..or ask another question

Comment: Once you have got that webview to load up. How would you go about adding a button so that the user can view the UITableView again?